# How to prove that function has infinite series?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

We know Maclaurin series expansion for many "standard" functions, like $e^x$, $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$, etc.

Often this expansion is used for approximating "hard" integrals or proving inequalities.

However, for what values is it true?

$$\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

This is Taylor series near $x=0$. Is it true when $x=2$?

If so, why?

There are also expansions near $\infty$. Wolframalpha says, that there is no expansion for sine near infinity. How are these expansions related and when to use an expansion near $\infty$?

Comment: A Taylor series is valid for any $x$ within its radius of convergence. For the 'standard' functions mentioned this radius includes the entire the complex plane.

Comment: @PeterForeman The Taylor series of $f(x)$ around $x=0$ is valid (i.e. converges to $f(x)$) for any $x$ within its radius of convergence **if** $f(x)$ is analytic within the radius of convergence.  The functions mentioned are analytic on the complex plane.